# How to sort a list, saving map from old positions to new positions?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq

I'd like to sort a list, and save a map from the old positions of the elements to their new positions?

For example, if the list to sort were

```
var words = "once upon a midnight dreary".Split();
// once upon a midnight dreary
```

Then the sorted list would be

```
var orderedWords = words.OrderBy(w => w).ToArray();
// a dreary midnight once upon
```

Then because 'once' moved from position 0 to position 3, the map would be

```
0 => 3, 1 => 4, 2 => 0, 3 => 2, 4 => 1
```

So that, for all i

```
words[i] = orderedWords[map[i]]
```

How can I do this?  I expect it should be possible in the same time complexity as ordinary sorting, ie. O(n log n)

---

I tried:

```
var map = words.Select((word, index) => new { Word = word, Index = index}).OrderBy(x => x.Word).Select(x => x.Index);
```

But this gives

```
> 2, 4, 3, 0, 1
```

Which fails the identity I gave above

```
for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    Assert.AreEqual(words[i], orderedWords[map[i]]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the new index after the `OrderBy`:

```
var map = words
    .Select((word, index) => new { Word = word, Index = index })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Word)
    .Select((x, NewIndex) => new { x.Word, x.Index, NewIndex });
```

Result:

```
[0] { Word = "a", Index = 2, NewIndex = 0 } 
[1] { Word = "dreary", Index = 4, NewIndex = 1 }    
[2] { Word = "midnight", Index = 3, NewIndex = 2 }
[3] { Word = "once", Index = 0, NewIndex = 3 }  
[4] { Word = "upon", Index = 1, NewIndex = 4 }
```

**Update**: acc. comment: "how do I get the 'old index to new index' data structure out?"

You could use a Dictionary:

```
var map = words
    .Select((word, index) => new { Word = word, OldIndex = index })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Word)
    .Select((x, NewIndex) => new { x.Word, x.OldIndex, NewIndex })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.OldIndex, x => x.NewIndex);

for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Word: {0} \tOldIndex: {1} \tNewIndex: {2}", words[i], i, map[i]);
}
```

Result:

```
Word: once      OldIndex: 0     NewIndex: 3
Word: upon      OldIndex: 1     NewIndex: 4
Word: a         OldIndex: 2     NewIndex: 0
Word: midnight  OldIndex: 3     NewIndex: 2
Word: dreary    OldIndex: 4     NewIndex: 1
```

Comment: Cool how do I get the 'old index to new index' data structure out?

Comment: @ColonelPanic: What do you mean?

Comment: I would like a data structure `map` that satisfies the identity / unit test in the question.i

Comment: @ColonelPanic: i have edited my answer. Maybe that is what you're looking for.